# Custom UITableViewCell with custom drawing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8, ios9

I have a custom subclass `UITableViewcell` which uses a `xib`. I have a custom edge drawing on a `CAShapeLayer` which I renew the drawing on all `layoutSubviews` calls.

The issue is frames are getting updated correctly on iOS 8.1, but not on 8.4 and 9.0.

Am I missing something?

Here is the custom `UITableViewCell`

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    [self.thumb.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];
    [self.thumb.layer setBorderColor:[[AppConfiguration color2] CGColor]];
    [self.thumb.layer setCornerRadius:self.thumb.frame.size.width / 2];
    [self.thumb setClipsToBounds:YES];

    self.containerBottom.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor r:189 g:189 b:189] CGColor];
    self.containerBottom.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    self.containerBottom.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
    self.containerBottom.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0f;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.containerTop.backgroundColor = self.color;

    if (self.masklayer.superlayer)
        [self.masklayer removeFromSuperlayer];

    [self drawing:self.containerTop];

    [self.containerTop.layer addSublayer:self.masklayer];

    self.containerTop.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    self.containerTop.clipsToBounds = NO;
}

+ (OperatorTableViewCell *)cell
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:nil options:nil];

    return [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

- (void)drawing:(UIView *)view;
{
    CGFloat radius = 5;

    NSInteger waves = floor((view.frame.size.width / (radius * 2)));
    radius = (view.frame.size.width / waves) / 2;

    NSLog(@"Frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(view.frame));

    self.masklayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(0, view.frame.size.height - 3);

    [path moveToPoint:point];

    for (int i=0; i < (view.frame.size.width / (radius * 2)); i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            point = CGPointMake(radius, point.y);
        }

        [path addArcWithCenter:point radius:radius startAngle:M_PI endAngle:M_PI * 2 clockwise:NO];
        point = CGPointMake(point.x + radius * 2, point.y);
    }

    self.masklayer.path = path.CGPath;
    self.masklayer.fillColor = view.backgroundColor.CGColor;
}
```

[image]

Please note that when I highlight the cell it causes layoutSubviews to get called and it fixes the issue. Which also seems weird to me. Highlighting the cell shouldn't cause a frame change.

Log

```
2015-10-18 04:38:18.736 app[12905:545562] Frame: {{8, 8}, {304, 82}}
2015-10-18 04:38:18.739 app[12905:545562] Frame: {{8, 8}, {304, 82}}
2015-10-18 04:38:23.577 app[12905:545562] Frame: {{8, 8}, {359, 82}}
2015-10-18 04:38:26.936 app[12905:545562] Frame: {{8, 8}, {359, 82}}
2015-10-18 04:38:54.608 app[12905:545562] Frame: {{8, 8}, {359, 82}}
2015-10-18 04:38:54.762 app[12905:545562] Frame: {{8, 8}, {304, 82}}
2015-10-18 04:38:54.763 app[12905:545562] Frame: {{8, 8}, {304, 82}}
2015-10-18 04:38:56.258 app[12905:545562] Frame: {{8, 8}, {359, 82}}
2015-10-18 04:38:57.155 app[12905:545562] Frame: {{8, 8}, {359, 82}}
```

Comment: Is `layoutSubviews` actually being called when you think it should be? Log and see.

Comment: on ios 8.1 it is. but not on 8.4 and 9.0.

Comment: So there you go. Problem solved. You are just _assuming_ that `layoutSubviews` is called at certain times. You can't assume that.

Comment: where should I be looking to get correct frames? frame is changing and I cannot track it.

Comment: Sorry but now I don't follow you. It seems to me the problem is solved. You were misusing `layoutSubviews` in some way. You need to stop doing that.

Comment: The issue here is my cell is being resized and only way I can track it is layoutSubviews. Where should I be doing my custom drawing if not in layoutSubviews. I want to track each frame change so I can redraw my custom layer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92619/discussion-between-bartu-and-matt).